# Direct link to comment in a thread on Yammer

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to get a link to a specific comment in a thread on [Yammer](https://www.yammer.com)?

I want to share a link to one comment, but I am only able to share or copy the link to the whole thread, which is not helpful for longer threads. All options to get a link (see red marks in the picture) just point to the whole thread, e.g.:

```
https://www.yammer.com/company/threads/12341234
```

The `SHARE` option does not give a link either, it just lets me share this thread in another group.

Is it possible to get a link to just one specific comment in a thread on Yammer?

[image]

Comment: I think this is only possible via their REST API

Comment: Do you have a more directed link / hint? I am not finding this in the API docs at https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesin_threadthreadidjson

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can obtain the message id of the specific comment (which are no different than any other post or update), then you can use the below URL to link directly to it.

`https://www.yammer.com/{network}/messages/{id}`

I don't have access to our Yammer network right now (away from my office) so I'm not able to comment on how you would obtain the message id.

Comment: I hope this helps;

- First of all get all the messages in a specific thread in JSON format, calling this REST API endpoint like;

`uri = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_thread/" + $threadID +".json?page=" + $pageNo`

you can also paginate through the results with the use of $pageNo parameter (if given)


- iterate through the messages array in JSON with your preferred programming language and pick the one you want for further processing